# How to write a rest api with multiple ways needed to fetch data

Tags: sql, node.js, database, rest, express

I am creating a REST API for a point of sale database at my workplace.

The thing is, depending on the situation I'm attempting to get the same result (an item from the 'Stock' table) with different inputs.

For instance we have a barcode table that points to a StockID, StockID being the primary key for Stock table rows, we also have a 'part code' for ordering reference, a part code is the code our suppliers use to reference items we hold, and we have a table very similar to the barcode table where a partcode points towards a StockID.

Problem with that is sometimes there are 2 rows in the PartCode table that have the same part code key but point to two different stock items. Meaning I cant just have more obvious REST API calls.

Currently I have my URLS like so:

> example.com/stockid/{123} (Probably the only logical REST call)
>
> example.com/barcode/{123} (This takes in a barcode, does one SQL query, gets the actual stock row its correlated and responds with that
>
> example.com/partcode/{123} (This does similar as above, although there are instances where the partcode is related to multiple row results

Now this is the second in depth REST API I've had to create and the first was alot easier because I was building a web app and could follow good conventions. But I am at a loss on how to start writing this REST API properly, all information I've found seems like it would work effectively or be clean and efficient for a code base and I would like to do this properly and keep it as maintainable as possible.

**Things to note**

- I have no capacity to change the structure of the database itself
- I am using NodeJS + ExpressJS as a backend server for writing this REST API
- I am happy to start fresh with whatever would seem to be the most practical and logical way to write this
- I am stuck because I don't want to have a huge amount of ambiguous and otherwise useless API URLs, I just want a proper way to reference the Stock table given the different ways it needs to be searched
- The database is a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would try to read a bit about [request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req), [response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res),[router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) of expressjs from expressjs official.

I have a CLI to start REST api named [Spready](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spready) with good practice means proper way how should start. I can recommend that and Database, you can find nodeJS ORM for MSSQL.

Comment: I understand how to use ExpressJS, I am just not sure how to format the API considering what im working with

Comment: well, follow REST standards resource-based routing. 
```example.com/barcodes``` [POST (to add new one) ,GET(to get all barcodes)]
```example.com/barcodes/{id}``` [GET (to read single barcode with unquie id), PUT(to update Single barcode by id) , DELETE ( to delete as well) 

But Yeah you have complex logic and table column you have to write some other custom endpoint. No worries about that cause most of the time in real product we have to write custom endpoints besides REST.

Comment: Yeah but i wont be adding barcodes (And if I eventually add that, I understand thats how it should be written). I just dont know how I should write the example.com/stock when i have so many different identifiers pointing at it

Comment: then write custom endpoint as you need and make $or query to get same formatted data for different identifiers. e.g that query params (id) would be stock id or barcode id etc.